# Date Java to MySql DateTime

Tags: java, mysql, networking, date

every body. I am getting this error:
        `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
        corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
        syntax to use near '14:37:41)' at line 1`
for this piece of code

```
       public String addName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date();
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        String currentTime = sdf.format(dt);



        String name = "RandomName";

        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost", "ericman", "ericman");
        Statement stat = (Statement) connect.createStatement();
        String insert = "INSERT INTO `bookcatalog`.`puch` (`name`, `time`) VALUES ('"
                + name + "', " + currentTime + ")";
        stat.executeUpdate(insert);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return "Name Updated";
}
```

Any suggestion of why this happening, I suck on structured language just so you know :)

Comment: It is wrong for the inserting of Dates into strings...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `PreparedStatement`.

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO `bookcatalog`.`puch` (`name`, `time`) VALUES (?,?)";
PreparedStatement ps=connect.prepareStatement(insert);
ps.setString(1,name);
ps.setTimeStamp(2,TimeStamp.valueOf(currentTime));
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `'` characters around your currentTime in the insert statement.

However, you really should be using a prepared statement for such things, to guard against SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Try convert string to date by [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to encapsulate the date/time in your `INSERT` statement with inverted commas, like you do with the name argument?

Answer (score 1):

ugh.  Why don't you use a PreparedStatement instead?

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO bookcatalog.puch(name, time) values ?,?");
stmt.setString(1, name);
stmt.setTimestamp(2, dt);
stmt.execute();
```

It's far cleaner.

Comment: I am very bad in MySQL language. Would you please demonstrate, how your code would replace my bad code? Thank you!!

Comment: See the example linked by @AVD above.

Comment: It says to I should cast the timestamp, and so I did. I cant see any Link neither AVD user? Thank you!